# Função DATE_FORMAT - Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tenho esta query abaixo, que traz todas as informações que necessito. Porem o campo resolution esta com a data (yy-mm-dd), necessito que ele retorne com a data formarada como dd/mm/yy:

```
select * 
FROM denuncia 
WHERE resolution BETWEEN ('2018-01-01') AND ('2018-12-31') 
ORDER BY resolution ASC;
```

Com esta query, traz a data formatada:

```
select resolution, DATE_FORMAT( `resolution` , '%d/%c/%Y' ) AS `resolution` 
FROM denuncia;
```

Não consigo juntar estas duas queryes para que faça o primeiro select e traga as datas formatadas conforme o segundo.

Comment: Use outro alias para a data formatada, exemplo AS `resolution_label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode especificar os campos que quer trazer da tabela:

```
select id, DATE_FORMAT( `resolution` , '%d/%c/%Y' ) AS `resolution`/*, demais_campos*/
FROM denuncia 
WHERE resolution BETWEEN ('2018-01-01') AND ('2018-12-31') 
ORDER BY resolution ASC;
```

Comment: Boa, deu certo. Obrigado.